# Azure Container App: trying to serve image through additonal port

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have an Azure Container app that is currently working with port 8050 opened up to all traffic as an additional TCP port.  The problem that I am having is this:  in my python code, I am trying to surface several images through port 8050 (e.g. mydomain.azurecontainerapps.io:8050/route/image.png) The images do not load, and I see this error when I inspect the browser:  ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.  If I try to open the image in another tab, I can get it to load using "http" instead of "https" on port 8050.  Is it impossible to get ssl over the tcp ports?  If so, I suppose I can try to change the route to go over the main port.

[image]